# Optimizing: a set of three lineair equations and a nonlineair max function

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

First of all, I am sorry for the title but I do not know what I am actually looking for.

I have the following three equations:
$$
A = \frac{1}{x}\\
B = \frac{s + 1}{4}\\
C = \frac{s}{x} + \frac{1-s}{4}
$$
And I know that:
$$
2 < x \leq 4\\
0 \leq s \leq 1
$$
And I want to maximize the following function:
$$
\min(A, B) - C = \min(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{s+1}{4}) - \frac{s}{x} - \frac{1-s}{4}
$$

All I have basically figured out is that his is in fact not a lineair optimization (because of the $\frac{s}{x}$ term). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $$\min(\frac{1}{x},\frac{s+1}{4})-\frac{2}{x}-\frac{1-s}{4}$$ with
$$2<x\le 4$$ and $$0\le s\le 1$$
For $$\frac{1}{x}\geq \frac{s+1}{4}$$  you have to maximize 
$$f(x,s)=\frac{s+1}{4}-\frac{s}{x}-\frac{1-s}{4}$$ and i have got $$(\frac{1}{16};s=\frac{1}{2},x=\frac{8}{3})$$
in the other case 
$$f(x,s)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{s}{x}-\frac{1-s}{4}$$ and here i have got
$$(\frac{1}{16};x=\frac{8}{3},s=\frac{1}{2})$$

Comment: The goal is to maximize, not to minimize.

Comment: Sorry i had it written on my paper, but forgotten to type in

Comment: Cool, thank you! How did you solve this?